# My code for constructing n-odd magic squares isn't working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to construct n-odd magic squares through the [Siamese method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_method)

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N; cin >> N;
    int magicsquares[N][N];
    memset(magicsquares, 0, sizeof(magicsquares));

    int i = 0, j = N/2;
    int num = 1;
    while (num <= N*N){

        if (magicsquares[i][j] == 0){
            magicsquares[i][j] = num++;
            i = (i-1+N) % N;    
            j = (j+1) % N;
        } else{
            i = (i+2) % N;
            j = (j-1+N) % N;
            magicsquares[i][j] = num++;
        } 
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < N; b++)
            cout << magicsquares[a][b] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I typed in 3, I expected it to come out like this:

```
8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2
```

But  it came out like this:

```
0 9 0
3 0 8
7 0 2
```

What's wrong with my code? I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

In the `if` branch (unfilled square), you fill a square and then set up `i` and `j` to point to the next square to be filled. When you encounter a filled square (`else` branch), you reverse the change in `i` and `j` and go down as per the algorithm, and fill it. But after that, you are not setting up `i` and `j` for the next move, like in the `if` branch. Setting `i` and `j` should be there for both branches. This should work:

```
    if (magicsquares[i][j] == 0){
        magicsquares[i][j] = num++;
    } else{
        i = (i+2) % N;
        j = (j-1+N) % N;
        magicsquares[i][j] = num++;
    } 
    i = (i-1+N) % N;    /* Setting up i and j for next fill */
    j = (j+1) % N;      /* This should be done in both cases */
```